# QT/codesign - Unable to sign QtWebEngineProcess with --options runtime

Tags: macos, qt, codesign, qwebengine

I sign my app like this:

```
codesign --deep --force --verify --verbose  --sign "CERTIFICATE" --entitlements ./QtWebEngineProcess.entitlements --options runtime ./MyApp.app
```

Inside `/QtWebEngineProcess.entitlements` I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-executable-page-protection</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I execute the command with no errors. However when I start my app looks like it can't properly load any WebPage. In the terminal I observe these warning/errors:

```
[24413:11297630:20231030,010843.805451:WARNING in_range_cast.h:38] value -634136515 out of range
[24413:11297630:20231030,010843.813111:WARNING crash_report_exception_handler.cc:257] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)
[24413:11297630:20231030,010843.933477:WARNING in_range_cast.h:38] value -634136515 out of range
[24413:11297630:20231030,010843.941292:WARNING crash_report_exception_handler.cc:257] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)
[24413:11297630:20231030,010844.059220:WARNING in_range_cast.h:38] value -634136515 out of range
[24413:11297630:20231030,010844.066488:WARNING crash_report_exception_handler.cc:257] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)
[24413:11297630:20231030,010844.180254:WARNING in_range_cast.h:38] value -634136515 out of range
[24413:11297630:20231030,010844.187770:WARNING crash_report_exception_handler.cc:257] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)
[24413:11297630:20231030,010844.303606:WARNING in_range_cast.h:38] value -634136515 out of range
[24413:11297630:20231030,010844.311464:WARNING crash_report_exception_handler.cc:257] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)
[24413:11297630:20231030,010844.427331:WARNING in_range_cast.h:38] value -634136515 out of range
[24413:11297630:20231030,010844.434919:WARNING crash_report_exception_handler.cc:257] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)
[24413:11297630:20231030,010844.563522:WARNING in_range_cast.h:38] value -634136515 out of range
[24413:11297630:20231030,010844.571230:WARNING crash_report_exception_handler.cc:257] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)
```

If I want to run my app and it to load web views/pages with no problems I have to run this command:

```
codesign --force --verify --verbose  --sign "CERTIFICATE" --entitlements ./QtWebEngineProcess.entitlements  ./MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/A/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/QtWebEngineProcess
```

Basically removing `--options runtime`. However if I do that this leads to another issue when trying to notarise the app which is expected:

```
{
  "severity": "error",
  "code": null,
  "path": "MyApp.zip/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/A/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/QtWebEngineProcess",
  "message": "The executable does not have the hardened runtime enabled.",
  "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087724",
  "architecture": "x86_64"
},
```

That pretty much mean that I have to have `MyApp.zip/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/A/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/QtWebEngineProcess` signed with `--option runtime`, but if I do that I am unable to load any web pages in my Qt app.

Looks like a dead end. Anyone have solved this issue before or can give an advice ?

Comment: Discord is crashing with exactly this error for me: `in_range_cast.h(38)] value -634136515 out of range`